# Avoid company backend in a specific mode

Tags: company-mode

In my dot-emacs I have the following backend for Company:

```
 (add-to-list 'company-backends 'company-dabbrev t)
```

In Eshell, I use another company backends. So it's configured as the following:

```
 (add-hook 'eshell-mode-hook
        (lambda ()
          (set (make-local-variable 'company-backends)
               '((company-shell company-eshell-history)))))
```

But in `eshell-mode` Company is also using `company-dabbrev` backend for the completion candidates, next to the backends `company-shell` and `company-eshell-history`.

So I'm wondering how I could 'tell' company do not use `company-dabbrev` backend when the buffer is in `eshell-mode`. I couldn't find any answer/solution on this.

Comment: What (buffer-local) value of `company-backends` do you see in an `eshell-mode` buffer?

Comment: `C-h v company-backends` in `eshell-mode` buffer gives me the following: http://pastebin.com/WwZqFCxs I find that weird, given the fact I see the results coming from `company-shell` and `company-eshell-history` but I don't  see it back in the value of `company-backends`.

Comment: Either way, there's some other code that modifies `company-backends` for you. Maybe you can ask someone (in a Spacemacs support channel?) how and why. In a vanilla Emacs, your solution should work.

Comment: @Dmitry May I ask why you assumed I could use Spacemacs?  I maintain my own Spacemacs.

Comment: The value of `company-backends` in your paste looks similar to how Spacemacs uses `company-yasnippet`.